# How to sum column in database using php

Tags: php, database

i'm trying to sum a column name "total". and i want to display the total sorting by id. if user A login he can see total booking in his account.

I keep get the error:

> "Notice:  Array to string conversion in  Array."

can someone help me? I want to echo the total in input form.

this is my php code:

```
<?php
    include ('connect.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM penjaga WHERE p_username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $id = $row['p_id'];

    $sql2 = "SELECT SUM(total) as total FROM sitter_kucing WHERE sitter_fk = '$id'";
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $sum = $row['total'];
?>
```

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address immediately

Comment: Your code is not correct with basic things, correct it first.

Comment: also - have you var_dumped $row and $row2 to make sure they're returning what you expect?

Comment: you need to pass `$sql2` here `$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql);`

Comment: You need to make a call to `mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$sql2 = "SELECT SUM(total) as total FROM sitter_kucing WHERE sitter_fk = '$id'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());

$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2) or die(mysql_error());
$sum = $row['total'];
```

Comment: thanks it works!! but i change a little bit. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

i got it! thanks this is my code

this is the code:

```
  <?php

   include ('connect.php');

   $sql8 = "SELECT * FROM penjaga WHERE p_username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
   $result8 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql8);
   $row8 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result8);
   $id = $row8['p_id'];

   $sql9 = "SELECT SUM(total) as total FROM sitter_kucing WHERE sitter_fk = '$id'";
   $result9 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql9);
   $row9 = mysqli_fetch_array($result9);
   $sum = $row9['total'];
   ?>
```